# jQuery: when slider form slides down its sliding from the top

Tags: jquery, css, margin, slidetoggle

I have a standard drop-down form that you click the link and it brings the form down.

The issues i am having are that:

1) When you click on the icon to drop the box down, it slides from the top of the div rather than from below (see my link as an example). I have tried adding a margin top to the hidden div so it slides down under the icon and also a z-index but nothing seems to happen. Silly thing is that i have a similar icon on the site that i have got to work this way but when applying the same styling to this icon slider it doesn't appear to apply!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/kyBRZ/3/

```
$(this).find('form').slideToggle();
```

Comment: ** In my original code i have a background image rather than text... not sure if this information is relevant or not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to solve it.

```
   #like form {
        position:relative;
        top:50px;
        display:none;
        width:180px;
        background:#ebece7;
        padding:20px;
        border:1px solid blue;
        height:150px;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyBRZ/4/)

Comment: Thanks, feel daft i forgot to check for positioning!